# Nodejs crashes during development cause continuous 'EADDRINUSE: address already in use'. Workaround?

Tags: node.js, linux, atom-editor, nodemon, manjaro

I'm working on a node.js script and it crashes sometimes because it's still in development. Every time this happens though I get an EADDRINUSE error and I have to go `ps ax | grep 'node server'` and then `kill the_pid`. This is extremely time consuming. There must be a work around. Is there?

Comment: Are you working with loops?
How can the nodejs process stay running if it crashes?

Comment: @PIDZB No loops. It appears to continue to run in the background as I'm able to find and kill the PID via the command listed above.

Answer (score 1):

I had nodemon installed globally. I uninstalled the global installation. I installed it as a dev dependency and that appears to have solved the problem; I no longer get the address in use error.